# What is the shortest writing of the equation containing this partial derivative?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, notation, partial-derivative

So, I have a function $f_{y^{\prime}}\left(x_{n}, y_{n}\right)=-\frac{y_{n}}{\left(\sqrt{x_{n}^{2}+y_{n}^{2}}\right)^{3}}$.

I wanna to derive $f_{y^\prime}\left(x_{n}+h a_{21} k_{1 x^{\prime}}, y_{n}+h a_{21} k_{1 y^{\prime}}\right)$ with respect to $a_{21}$. In this case $x_n$, $h$,$k_{1y^\prime}$ and $k_{1x^{\prime}}$ are independent over $a_{21}$ so I treat them as a constants.

I write the partial derivative like this
$\frac{\partial f_{y^\prime}\left(x_{n}+h a_{21} k_{1 x^{\prime}}, y_{n}+h a_{21} k_{1 y^{\prime}}\right)}{\partial a_{21}} 
=\left(f_{y^{\prime}_{1}} h k_{1x^{\prime}} +f_{y^{\prime}_{2}} h k_{1 y^{\prime}}\right)$

$f_{y^{\prime}_{i}}$ mean derivavite partial $f_{y^{\prime}}$ for $i$-th component. I think that is not clear since the input function not clear whether  $(x_{n}, y_{n})$ or $\left(x_{n}+h a_{21} k_{1 x^{\prime}}, y_{n}+h a_{21} k_{1 y^{\prime}}\right)$. But I want to write as short as possible. What is the shortest writing of the equation containing this partial derivative?

Comment: What happened to the $y'$ subscript on the right-hand side?

Comment: I've just edited my question. Sorry, but I don't understand your question. I think it's clear right now.

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't. Your function is called $f_{y'}$ –or perhaps this denotes a derivative – in any case, the question is, how does that subscript $y'$ get lost on the right-hand side of your partial derivative? If it's part of the name of the function, it should stay there, and if it indicates a partial derivative, it should also stay there.

Comment: Where does subscript $y^{\prime}$ get lost on the right-hand side? It's still. That is a function name.

Comment: Ah, I think I see now – you mean $f_{y'1}$ and $f_{y'2}$? You wrote $f_{y'_1}$ and $f_{y'_2}$.

Comment: Yes, I mean like that.